# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT] Express server crashing in node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure-sql-database

So this code works fine and does everything, but continues to crash my express server.
This is the error:
node:internal/errors:464
ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:576:11)
at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\user\dragonfitness\crud-application\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:776:10)
at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\user\dragonfitness\crud-application\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\user\dragonfitness\crud-application\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\user\dragonfitness\crud-application\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:158:21)
at Request. (C:\Users\user\dragonfitness\crud-application\server\index.js:89:11) {
code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'

```
app.post('/login', async (req, res)=>{
  try{
    var sql = "SELECT password FROM dbo.user_info WHERE user_name = @username"
    const request = new Request(sql,
      (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err.message)
        }
        if(result == 0){
          console.log("failed")
          return res.send({message: "Wrong username/password combination"})
        }
      }  
    );
    request.on('row', async function(columns) {
      console.log(columns)
      const password =columns[0].value;
      console.log(req.body.passwordlog)
      console.log(password)
    const isValid = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.passwordlog, password)
    if(isValid){
      console.log("passed")
      return res.send({message: "Login Sucessful"})
    }
    });
    request.addParameter('username', TYPES.NVarChar, req.body.usernamelog)
  
    connection.execSql(request);
  }catch{
    console.log("better not")
    return res.status(500).send()
  }
  });
```

the console.logs are working perfect and sends the request back to the front end just fine. and does what it's suppose to but it crashes my express server. Any help?

Comment: That particular error happens when you try to send more than one response to the same request.  For example, if you call `res.send()` more than once.  I don't know your database so I can't really analyze where that might be possible in this code.  Certainly if you ever got more than one `row` event that matched the password, you would call `res.send()` more than once.

Comment: To give you some debugging help, I'd suggest adding a specific labeled `console.log()` right before each `res.send()` in this function and see which ones are getting called.

Comment: It also seems like in your `if (err) { ... }` block, you need to send an error response and return.

Comment: If you have more than one matching row, then the `request.on('row', ...)` handler will be called more than once.

Answer (score 1):

> Return res.send() eveywhere

```
 return res.send({message: "Wrong username/password combination"})
```

and

```
return res.send({message: "Login Sucessful"})
```

You are trying to send response multiple times. Apply return to each and every res.send() statement and it will work fine.

Comment: ok I added console.logs before each res.send and added return to the front of them. So I learned that my if(isValid) is being called twice because it returns passed two times in the console. Does anyone know why it is being called twice?